# Undo / Redo Bitmap is not properly working

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

I have been stuck on this for a few days now and it's really beyond me why I can't get something so simple to work. I have a small drawing applicaiton, quite similiar to the Android FingerPaint demo, but I am saving each Bitmap after a drawing happens. This is because I plan to add a fill tool to my application later, and it's easier just to load the newly filled bitmap onto the canvas, instead of figuring out how to save the fill as a stroke to re-draw onto the canvas.

The drawing works great - the problem is, I can't undo and redo. I have tried with the code below, but nothing gets undone or redone. In theory, on `undo`, the mBitmapsDrawn should remove it's most recent Bitmap and push that onto the `mBitmapsUndone` stack, and then the method `loadSurfaceBitmap()` is called to draw the Bitmap that was saved before the one we just undid.

For `redo`, the `mBitmapsUndone` stack should pop the top Bitmap and push it back into `mBitmapsDrawn`, to then be re-loaded onto the Canvas by `loadSurfaceBitmap()`.

When clicking redo/undo, no changes to the visual canvas happen, **but** the sizes of the data structures change (since I have log statemenets checking before and after, and they decrease/increase in size. So I think my problem is in the actual rendering of the latest bitmap in `mBitmapsDrawn` after a redo/undo happens.

```
private Stack<Bitmap> mBitmapsDrawn = new Stack<>();
private Stack<Bitmap> mBitmapsUndone = new Stack<>();

protected void touchStart(float x, float y) {
       
        mBitmapsUndone.clear();

        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
        onDraw();
    }

    protected void touchMove(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
            onDraw();
        }
    }

    protected void touchUp() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);

        // Add path to list of paths to draw
        onDraw();
        mBitmapsDrawn.push(mBitmap);
        loadSurfaceBitmap();

        // Kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath = new Path();

        mPaint = new Paint(mPaint);

        mIsDrawing = false;
    }

    protected void onDraw() {
        if (mCanvas == null) {
            return;
        }

        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    protected void loadSurfaceBitmap() {
        if (mBitmapsDrawn.size() != 0) { 
              mBitmap = mBitmapsDrawn.peek();
        } else {
              mBitmap = mBgBitmap;
        }
        Canvas surfaceCanvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        surfaceCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(surfaceCanvas);
    }

    protected void undo() {
        int undoSize = mBitmapsUndone.size();
        int drawnSize = mBitmapsDrawn.size();
        if (drawnSize > 0) {
            Bitmap removedBitmap = mBitmapsDrawn.pop();
            mBitmapsUndone.push(removedBitmap);
            loadSurfaceBitmap();
        }
    }

protected void redo() {
        int undoSize = mBitmapsUndone.size();
        int pathsSize = mBitmapsDrawn.size();
        if (undoSize > 0) {
            Bitmap mostRecentUndo = mBitmapsUndone.pop();
            mBitmapsDrawn.push(mostRecentUndo);
            loadSurfaceBitmap();
        }
    }
```

TLDR: I'm having issues popping a stack / adding to an ArrayList when undo'ing / redo'ing in my application, where I should be changing the bitmap that is loaded on the surface, but it never happens.

**Edit: Updated code per the answer, still no luck. Redo doesn't change the visual bitmap on the surface.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your drawing works fine it doesn't seem like there's a rendering problem - it's all calling `loadSurfaceBitmap()` the same way, right? I don't know if handling a touch event makes a difference and if you need to call `invalidate()` otherwise - I've never poked at surface canvases like this.

Your *undo* code is a little strange though

```
Bitmap removedBitmap = mBitmapsUndone.remove(drawnSize - 1);
mPathsUndone.push(removedBitmap);
loadSurfaceBitmap();
```

You're removing a bitmap from your `Undone` stack when you should be removing it from your `Drawn` list - I'm assuming that's why you're doing `remove(size - 1)` instead of just `pop()`, because you meant to remove from the `List` instead of the `Stack` (why not just use two `Stack`s anyway?).

Then you place it onto something called `mPathsUndone` which is maybe a typo from renaming *Paths* to *Bitmaps* for the question? If so your undo code is removing a bitmap from the undo stack, then putting it back on top - otherwise it's going somewhere mysterious. (You're also using the size of the *drawn* list to get an index for the *undo* stack so that will cause big problems too)

Your *redo* code looks fine to me, I'm guessing the only problem is that your *undo* code wasn't actually adding anything to its stack, so there's nothing to redo. I'm guessing this might fix it:

```
protected void undo() {
    int undoSize = mBitmapsUndone.size();
    int drawnSize = mBitmapsDrawn.size();
    if (drawnSize > 0) {
        Bitmap removedBitmap = mBitmapsDrawn.remove(drawnSize - 1);
        mBitmapsUndone.push(removedBitmap);
        loadSurfaceBitmap();
    }
}
```

I feel like using stacks for both would be more intuitive since it's a nice pop one, push the other flow, but that's up to you!

---

**edit** here's some code updating the file you posted, something like this should work:

```
protected void onDraw() {
    if (mCanvas == null) {
        return;
    }
    // a new drawing event needs a new bitmap layer to draw it on,
    // starting with the contents of the current layer
    mBitmap = mBitmap.copy(mBitmap.getConfig(), true);
    // we also need a canvas for the new bitmap so we can draw on it
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mFgPaint);
}
```

Personally I'd probably move the "add this bitmap to `mBitmapsDrawn`" code here too, as well as the "draw the current bitmap to the surface" code - you're doing those in `touchUp` but I feel like they're more directly related to the action of drawing, and `touchUp` is more about finalising a touch gesture and initiating the draw call. Up to you!

Here's how I'd probably organise this, if it helps. Since every draw event creates a new bitmap, you don't need to keep a reference to a bitmap's `Canvas` - you'll have to create a new one anyway. I'd do the rest this way:

```
getCurrentBitmap() {
    return the top of mBitmapsDrawn, or if empty, the background bitmap
}

drawCurrentBitmap() {
    calls getCurrentBitmap(), draws it to the Surface
}

undo() {
    pops a bitmap off Drawn and pushes onto Undo, calls drawCurrentBitmap()
}

redo() {
    pops a bitmap off Undo and pushes onto Drawn, calls drawCurrentBitmap()
}

drawPath() {
    call getCurrentBitmap to get a source image
    create a new bitmap from that
    create a canvas for it and draw to it
    push the bitmap onto Drawn
    clear Undo
    call drawCurrentBitmap
}
```

So everything's really about manipulating the drawn and undo stacks, and every time the drawn one changes, you call a function that displays the image on top of it. And having a `getCurrentBitmap` function puts that logic in one place, so everything that updates the stack doesn't also need to worry about updating `mBitmap` with the appropriate value.

I'll also say, storing bitmaps like this works fine, but it's pretty inefficient - your memory usage could start to pile up quickly! Since you're doing drawing operations, you might want to think about storing representations of *those* instead, so you can get the "current" image by replaying all the past draw operations in order.

You could get fancy and cache a bitmap of the result of all but the most recent operations, and replay the most recent ones on top of that to make redrawing faster - but you'd still have all those operations in your history, almost infinite undo. Just something to consider maybe!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, I'm glad to get some eyes on this. Sorry, yeah that is a typo when I was retyping onto SO, and I've gone ahead and updated my post with the correct variables (and also changed to using a Stack per your valid suggestion).

Unfortunately, the problem still is that while clicking undo changes the Stack sizes, the visual Bitmap loaded on the surface remains unchanged. I'm thinking it has something to do with mBitmap, but I'm not too sure...

Comment: An example: if I draw "1", then draw "2", then draw "3", I currently have "1 2 3" on my surface, but if I click undo, mDrawnBitmaps.size() = 2 and mBitmapsUndone = 1, but the surface still is showing the bitmap with "1 2 3" instead of "1 2"

Comment: @gosen32993 the only thing I can think of is that `onDraw` is getting called, which only draws your current `mPath`, and no bitmaps. So maybe the code in `loadSurfaceBitmap` isn't working at all (it seems ok but I've only ever handled drawing in `onDraw` personally) or maybe it does work, but then `onDraw` gets called soon after and the whole canvas is wiped and needs redrawing. But your `onDraw` method is weird - what are you subclassing here, it's not a `View` right? If you post the full class I can take a look and see if I can work it out (and learn a bit about drawing options too)

Comment: No, I'm subclassing the Android Service class. Sure, this is my full class (for the most part, needed to remove some unnecessary things / things I can't include), but it has everything part of the worflow. Note, Bitmap/Canvas is initialized in `onAvailable`, and everything else is in `init()`. The finer details about the CustomSurfaceHolder is not important, it basically just extends the `SurfaceHolder` class and that's really all. The `recieveMessage` calls all the draw methods: https://pastebin.com/LyYPmD3T

Comment: Thanks for offering to take a look, I'm really hoping to get through this so I can continue developing this! The main focus would be the `recieveMessage()` method, alongside the specific drawing/action methods like: `touchStart(), touchMove(), touchUp(), onDraw(), redo(), undo(), loadSurfaceBitmap()`

Comment: @gosen32993 ok, from what I can tell your problem is you're not actually creating any new bitmaps! You're just using `mBitmap` and adding references to that to your stack, so it's just copies of the same thing that all change as the drawing happens. I updated my answer with a few suggestions, but basically you need to create a new bitmap whenever you do a draw operation

Comment: Thank you so much! I just tried it out (https://pastebin.com/2WyJyP8r) and it definitely helps! I can undo / redo strokes. However, it doesn't live-draw, whatever I draw only displays on the canvas AFTER touch-up, is there a way I can remedy that? Also: in terms of the saving bitmaps, I did that because I have a fill algorithm (floodfill), which currently has two problems: 1, I can't properly undo it (same issue I think), and also I can't save a fill as a Path, to then re-draw onto the canvas in my experience, which is why I thought saving bitmaps and loading those would be better.

Comment: @gosen32993 for the live-drawing thing, it depends how you wanted to do it. Each "drawing operation" involves *touch down -> moves -> touch up* which produces a finshed path drawn to a bitmap. So you could create the new bitmap on *down* (when a new operation is started) and just draw to the current bitmap during *move* and *up*. **Or** you could not draw the in-progress path to a bitmap at all, just draw it onto the `Surface`'s canvas (allowing the user to move it around without making it permanent, say dragging a line's end point) and only commit it to a bitmap when they do *touch up*

Comment: @gosen32993 as for the bitmaps, you wouldn't necessarily be storing everything as a `Path`, just your own data structure that describes your different drawing operations. So if there's a fill operation that involves tapping at *(x, y)* with a particular fill colour, you could have a class that represents that. If there's a path operation, you have a class that represents that (and it could just hold an actual `Path` internally if you wanted!). The idea really is to just store the events that are being triggered - I mean technically, you could just store the JSON you're using and replay that!

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! Moving the logic to touchStart was the solution! I appreciate it so much - I think there is still a problem with the undo, being that it undo's all the fills at once / filling breaks the logic of undo'ing one operation at a time. & In regard to the data structure comment, I tried that out this morning and it works, the problem is it's too memory intensive to keep re-drawing fill operations, but I'll give it a deeper dive once I can fix this undo issue now. Do you have any immediete thoughts on that? Thanks!

Comment: @gosen32993 so long as you're doing the fills the same way (new operation creates a new bitmap layer) it shouldn't be any different from drawing a path, in the end it's just pixels on a bitmap that you're storing. I think you probably need to break up your logic so the final drawing/commit is the same for everything - having a custom data structure might help with that, because you could pass a final operation object (path, fill) to a draw function when it's ready, and then the touch handlers basically build that object and pass it over when it's done. One way to abstract it into a common API!

Comment: You can ignore the previous comments, I deleted one as I kept updating while making progress - it looks like it's completely working, thank you very much for your help in this! I just want to address the custom data structure comment, I tried that this morning (saving "operations" into the DS and then re-drawing them all onto the canvas), but the problem is re-drawing so many fill operations at the same time makes the drawing too slow, so I don't know if that would be the best solution. I store DRAW, metadata or FILL, metadata, and then when re-creating it, it slows down the more fills I have.

Comment: As far as memory goes, whatever data you're storing in a custom object, it will take up way less memory than a bitmap! If you mean it's slow because of all the redrawing you need to replay from the beginning - I mentioned it earlier but you could cache a bitmap for that. If there's 30 operations in your history, you could draw the first 20, then store that as a bitmap. Then to redraw, you just need to draw that bitmap, and the remaining 10 operations. Kinda like a save state! It would take some work to juggle it, but you could make it performant *and* have a full history if you wanted

Comment: Yeah, I mean the re-drawing process to replay it from the beginning is the slowest part with fill operations. I'll look into the caching process though, sounds promising and looks like I wouldn't need to change too much in my logic to cache modified bitmaps - I just want to thank you again for taking the time to look through all this and help me out here!

Comment: @gosen32993 no worries, glad you got it working! I answered about speeding up drawing with a bitmap caching the state, hope that makes sense. You'd need to work out some logic for when to store/discard those bitmaps, and ideally being able to draw them in the background (in a coroutine or another thread or something) would let you get a new one ready in advance, since you have to redraw everything *at some point* to create that bitmap. It's a bit tricker than what you have so maybe it would be a version 2 kind of thing, Good look with it anyhow!